# Install Apache using tar without gcc compiler

Tags: apache

I am trying to install apache httpd using tar.gz but it is asking for gcc compilers and few more things.

Is there a way we can get a compiled version of apache httpd so that we can skip configuring it and install directly?

I am trying this on Linux ubuntu machine.

Comment: On what operating system? In Oracle Solairs, *BSD, and GNU/Linux distributions, pre-compiled binaries are available from package managers such as pkg, apt, yum, dnf, etc. On Windows, there's the installer available I believe, and in Cygwin environment, you use the installer "setup-x86(_64)?.exe" as package manager.

Comment: Sorry it is on Linux Ubuntu. But I am not allowed to use apt on it.